# MSAccess - Using Form's On_Unload event with runtime clients?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an app that is used by 2013 & 2010 users.  I have a collection of users still on Access 2007 for which I create a 2010 Runtime copy.  Everything has been working well for quite a while.

This weekend I moved some code from the MainForm's "On Close" event to a new "On Unload" event, as it seems to support my error handling a bit more consistently (exiting app for certain err.numbers, etc.).

The 2013 and 2010 users are fine.

The 2010 Runtime users are getting hung-up, without an error message, with initial login screen only partially rendered.

Any ideas if using the "On Unload" event in a runtime env is a known issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the code that is placed? Have you tried executing the full working file in the 2007 computer? If memory serves right A2007 is still capable of opening accdb files.

Comment: Stripping the On Unload code to just it's most basic elements (declarations, err_handling) only, w/no functions, seems to be OK.  I'll add-back the functions one-by-one to find the offender.

Comment: Argh, adding back the functions one-by-one, testing after each addition.  It all works now.  Huh?!

Comment: The only difference seems to be I have RETAINED the original "On Close" event but added a quick "Exit Sub" right at the front to bypass.  

Very Strange.  Maybe "On Unload" needs an accompanying "On Close" event, even though it does nothing??

Comment: It should not ! On Unload and On Close are two different and individual methods, does not need each other. Sometimes, sometimes only when copying and pasting code could make it go funny. You always should compile the code, when you perform a copy paste, so the compiler actually understands the new method. Anyway glad you have it sorted. Good luck !

Comment: You should do some logging to an external file to check where exactly the application hangs. For error handling and tracing I highly recommend [vbWatchdog](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp) it's been invaluable and well worth the money in helping identify where exactly errors occur and what is the current context at that point. Basically, to get to the bottom of these type of issues, you have to instrument your application to monitor it in real time. Having Virtual Machines set with the target environment are also very helpful to debug these environment-specific issues.